Compare-Object sorting with reference object
I have two files (for CNC controllers) that I want to compare. I can get the results just great with compare-object:
$Diffs = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CFFC -DifferenceObject $CSFC -IncludeEqual
The problem I'm having is that I want to then print out the results in the same file order as the reference object; A summary of what was changed and what was original. The Compare-Object results are sorted by SideIndicator, which makes it hard to compare exactly where the file has been changed.

EDIT1:
Below is a sample of the input and reference and the desired outputs.

...
Reference Object                          |Input Object
                                          |
X-17.7936 Y-7.4805 C-273.65               |X-17.7936 Y-7.4805 C-273.65               
X-17.9524 Y-4.9136 Z2.9619 C273.67        |X-17.9524 Y-4.9136 Z2.9619 C273.67        
X-17.7969 Y-5.1084 Z2.9812                |X-17.7969 Y-5.1084 Z2.9812                
G00 X-17.7795 Y-5.1073 Z3.981             |G00 X-17.7795 Y-5.1073 Z3.981             
X9.8237 Y-10.8339 Z7.404 A-29.001 C274.152|X9.8277 Y-10.8339 Z7.404 A-29.001 C274.152
Z1.9632                                   |Z1.9672                                   
G01 X9.7936 Y-10.3348 Z1.9674             |G01 X9.7966 Y-10.3348 Z1.9674             
X9.6413 Y-8.0055 Z1.9682 A-29.0 C-274.149 |X9.6513 Y-8.0055 Z1.9682 A-29.0 C-274.149 
G01 X7.6726 Y-4.7252 F200.0               |G01 X7.6726 Y-4.7252 F200.0               
X7.8804 Y-8.0949 Z2.9991 A16.73 C29.503   |X7.8804 Y-8.0949 Z2.9991 A16.73 C29.503   
X7.8782 Y-8.0951 Z2.9994 A16.791 C29.935  |X7.8782 Y-8.0951 Z2.9994 A16.791 C29.935  
X7.876 Y-8.0953 Z2.9997 A16.854 C30.363   |X7.876 Y-8.0953 Z2.9997 A16.854 C30.363   
X7.878 Y-8.0971 Z2.9988 A16.671 C-30.261  |X7.878 Y-8.0971 Z2.9988 A16.671 C-30.261  
X7.8805 Y-8.0994 Z2.9977 A16.437 C-30.131 |X7.8805 Y-8.0994 Z2.9977 A16.437 C-30.131 

...

Desired Output:
X-17.7936 Y-7.4805 C-273.65               |
X-17.9524 Y-4.9136 Z2.9619 C273.67        |
X-17.7969 Y-5.1084 Z2.9812                |
G00 X-17.7795 Y-5.1073 Z3.981             |
X9.8277 Y-10.8339 Z7.404 A-29.001 C274.152|Changed
Z1.9672                                   |Changed
G01 X9.7966 Y-10.3348 Z1.9674             |Changed
X9.6513 Y-8.0055 Z1.9682 A-29.0 C-274.149 |Changed
G01 X7.6726 Y-4.7252 F200.0               |
X7.8804 Y-8.0949 Z2.9991 A16.73 C29.503   |
X7.8782 Y-8.0951 Z2.9994 A16.791 C29.935  |
X7.876 Y-8.0953 Z2.9997 A16.854 C30.363   |
X7.878 Y-8.0971 Z2.9988 A16.671 C-30.261  |
X7.8805 Y-8.0994 Z2.9977 A16.437 C-30.131 |

I was able to do this with a foreach loop and creating a new variable, but it takes a horribly long time.
$NewArr=@()
foreach($line in $csfc){
    $ChangeStatus = ($Diffs -match [regex]::Escape($line)).SideIndicator
    $LineStatus = "" | Select LINE, TYPE
    if ($ChangeStatus -eq "=="){
        $LineStatus.line = $line
        $LineStatus.Type = $true
        }
    else{
        $LineStatus.line = $line
        $LineStatus.Type = $false
        }

    $newarr += $LineStatus
}

I'd like to know if there is a faster and more robust way to do this

Edit 1: For example, if a line is repeated 3 times in the input file and only twice in the reference, how do I catch that the 3rd line is new?


Are you sure the comparison you're looking for is for both sides? It seems you're only interested in finding if the items in the reference object exist in the difference object (meaning it is a one side comparison) in which case Compare-Object is pretty inefficient for that

My goal is to quickly confirm changes and ensure changes have not been inadvertently introduced when making updates or additions and creating a new document. So yes, it’s primarily one sided. Is there a more elegant solution?

Yup, there is and a much more efficient one but it would be helpful if instead you could provide a little sample of the reference list and a sample of the difference list and what you expect as a result instead of providing the sample output of your current code

try avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection as it is inefficiënt.

@SantiagoSquarzon - I made the edits to the original post showing what I'm hoping to achieve.
